# Need to display one element at start and another at extreme right

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ0ye.png)I am using this kind of react syntax and need to display bag name and price with price at extreme right near to dropdown

```
<Select className="bags-list">
  {(this.props.bags).map(bag => (
    <option key={ bag.Name } value={ bag.Name }>
      { bag.Name } {'$'}{(bag.sellPrice) ? bag.sellPrice : bag.Price}
    </option>
  )}
</Select>
```

Comment: At least format your code as code...

Comment: @MYS can you please share the image how do you want it looks like

Answer (score 0):

You can render whatever you want between your `<option />` tags.
So you could do something like this

```
<option key={bag.Name} value={bag.Name} className="option">
  <p>{bag.Name}</p>
  <p>`$ ${bag.sellPrice || bag.Price)}`</p>
</options>
```

Now you can style your option and it's children like you would with any other HTML tag. Something like this should do the trick:

```
.option {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```